# GitHub page using maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, github, github-pages

i created github repository, and pushed spring boot java project as maven in to that repository.
i set that repository to github page. and when i access to to that page it gives 404.
how can i access that page.

https://uniquethrowdown.github.io/VotingSyatem/

[GitHub Project](https://github.com/uniquethrowdown/VotingSyatem)

VotingSystem is my repository that i wanted to use as github page.

Comment: Have you tried everything listed on here: https://help.github.com/en/github/working-with-github-pages/creating-a-github-pages-site

Comment: First you should put your pom.xml in the root directory furthermore you need a branch which is called `gh-page` where you push the html files...